# Set matrix rotation in glm::mat4

Tags: matrix, rotation, glm-math, fbx

I'm trying to port some code from Autodesk FBX SDK to use glm instead. The Autodesk SDK has a class called `FbxAMatrix` (FBX affine matrix class - similiar to `glm::mat4`) which provides the funtion:

```
void SetR(const FbxVector4& pR); /* Set matrix's Euler rotation. X, Y and Z rotation values expressed as a vector. The rotation transform is constructed in rotation order XYZ. */
```

This function is supposed to set the rotation - while `glm::rotate()` will just rotate the matrix. In my understanding, these are two different operations - and if I run both functions with same inputs, the result is different too. The same problem happens, if I try to use `glm::eulerAngleXYZ()` instead.

IdentityMatrix:

```
{ 1, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 1, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 1, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 1 }
```

RotationVector:

```
{ 15 }
{ 0 }
{ 0 }
```

FbxAMatrix::IdentityMatrix.SetR(RotationVector):

```
 { 1, 0, 0, 0 }
 { 0, 0.96592582628906831, 0.25881904510252074, 0 } 
 { 0, 0.25881904510252074, 0.96592582628906831, 0 } 
 { 0, 0, 0, 1 }
```

glm::rotate(IdentityMatrix, 1.0f, RotationVector):

```
 { 1, 0, 0, 0 }
 { 0, 0.540302277, 0.841470957, 0 }
 { 0, 0.841470957, 0.540302277, 0 }
 { 0, 0, 0, 1 }
```

glm::eulerAngleXYZ(RotationVector):

```
 { 1, 0, 0, 0 }
 { 0, 0.759687901, 0.650287867, 0 }
 { 0, 0.650287867, 0.759687901, 0 }
 { 0, 0, 0, 1 }
```

So my question is: How can I set the rotation of an matrix with glm (to get smiliar results to `FbxAMatrix.SetR(RotationVector)`)? If there is no available function, I would like to understand the difference between rotate the identity matrix and set the rotation of the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glm::eulerAngleXYZ` does exactly what you need. The problem is that your autodesk function works with degrees, and glm with radians. You can see that non-unit numbers in `FbxAMatrix::SetR` section are sine and cosine of 15 degrees, and numbers in `glm::eulerAngleXYZ` are sine and cosine of 15. So, to have a needed equivalent you'd use:

```
glm::eulerAngleXYZ(
  x / 180 * PI,
  y / 180 * PI,
  z / 180 * PI
);
```

in your case being `x=15` and `y=z=0`.